# Unable to co connect SQL server Authentication with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect with PHP my SQL server.

I followed the doc PHP and I just replace with the goods data but I have this persisting error.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 28000 
        [SQLSTATE] => 28000 
        [1] => 18456 
        [code] => 18456 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxxx'. 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxxx'. 
    )

    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 42000 
        [SQLSTATE] => 42000 
        [1] => 4060 
        [code] => 4060 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "xxxx" requested by the login. The login failed. 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "xxxx" requested by the login. The login failed. 
    )

    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 28000 
        [SQLSTATE] => 28000 
        [1] => 18456 
        [code] => 18456 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxxx'. 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxxx'. 
    ) 

    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => 42000 
        [SQLSTATE] => 42000 
        [1] => 4060 
        [code] => 4060 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "xxxx" requested by the login. The login failed. 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "xxxx" requested by the login. The login failed. 
    )
)
```

It's ok, I'm understand what is the problem, but I'm sure, I replace correctly the data.

Look my PHP db connect :

```
<?php
$serverName = "myservername\\sqlexpress, 1433";     
$connectionInfo = array( 
    "Database"=>"DBname", 
    "UID"=>"login/connection", 
    "PWD"=>"password"
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt in the SQL Server's logs?

Comment: I haven't the autorisation for access to the logs ...

Comment: Speak to someone who does?

Comment: @Larnu He doesn't know if he got the access. I'm blocked here. I understand you can't help me more, thx for your helping bro